# Django Form not validating even with values filled

Tags: python, django, forms, file, upload

This is my first Django project and I am having trouble picking up the value in my form. I have created an UploadFileForm, implemented some basic code in the Views, and mapped the urls in the urls.py. My problem is occurring when I try to send input to my form. Even though my form is filled, it is giving me an error saying the fields are not filled. I have narrowed down my problem to the 'form.is_valid' function. Is there something I am missing in my code?

upload.html

```
<form action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ form.errors }}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UploadFileForm

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('uploaded.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^upload/success/', views.success, name='success'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload_file, name='upload_file'),
]
```

Comment: Did you complete *all* the tutorials and/or check the documentation?

Comment: I did check the documentation and followed it thoroughly, but the docs did not include the forms.py file.

Comment: You mention that the form.is_valid() is where you suspect a problem.  Try inserting "print(form.errors)" after the is_valid "if" block.  It might give you some insight into what is erroring out. Alternatively, if you are familiar with pdb, put an "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" before the is_valid call and step through the code.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/):  the `<form>` must have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I recall reading that in the docs and that was all I needed to save the file. Thanks a lot!